# MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I just built a simple app with mongoDB and nodejs, and I used `docker compose` to do whole packing process for my app, but when I run `docker-compose up` my mongo service is fine, but my node app cant connect to my mongo and crash, I research many way to resolve that problems on google, but Unfortunately it isn't still working for my app,

Hope everyone can help me,

Thank you

ex info:

structure my project:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPytK.png)

## Log error

```
connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo 

ENOTFOUND mongo
node-app_1  |     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:825:32)
node-app_1  |     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:409:10
node-app_1  |     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
node-app_1  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
node-app_1  |     at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
node-app_1  |     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1262:10)
node-app_1  |     at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:408:20)
node-app_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:9:10)
node-app_1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
node-app_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10) {
node-app_1  |   reason: TopologyDescription {
node-app_1  |     type: 'Unknown',
node-app_1  |     servers: Map(1) { 'mongo:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
node-app_1  |     stale: false,
node-app_1  |     compatible: true,
node-app_1  |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
node-app_1  |     localThresholdMS: 15,
node-app_1  |     setName: null,
node-app_1  |     maxElectionId: null,
node-app_1  |     maxSetVersion: null,
node-app_1  |     commonWireVersion: 0,
node-app_1  |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
node-app_1  |   },
node-app_1  |   code: undefined
node-app_1  | }
node-app_1  | node:internal/process/promises:225
node-app_1  |           triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
```

## Connection String:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo-db:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

## Dockerfile-node:

```
FROM node:15.3.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY package\*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

## Dockerfile-mongo:

```
FROM mongo:4.4

WORKDIR /data/db

VOLUME /data/db

EXPOSE 27017
 
CMD ["mongod"]
```

## docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-node
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    networks:
      - mongo-db
  mongo-db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongo-db
volumes:
  mongo-data:
networks:
  mongo-db:
    name: mongo-db
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update Answer

Dang, I realize my docker didn't rebuild when I type "docker-compose up" so it made up error 'ENOTFOUND mongo', so to resolve this problem you will remove that image in docker and type "docker-compose up" again,

It worked for me!